# Expansion of $(\sinh(x))^{\frac15}$ around 0 for x > 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I'm aware of the series expansion of the hyperbolic functions, but how does one expand a fractional power of sinus hyperbolicus, i.e. e.g. $(\sinh(x))^{\frac15}$?

Comment: Well, first you must choose a point around which to expand, because the somewhat obvious $x=0$ isn't viable ($\sqrt[5]{\sinh x}$ is not differentiable at $0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually approach these kind of expansions is by looking at the power series expansion of the inner and outer function. For this problem, the series expansion for $\sinh(x)$ (inner function) is given by
$$\sinh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\mathcal{O}(x^7)$$
and for the outer function we have
$$(1+x)^{\frac{1}{5}}=1+\frac{x}{5}-\frac{2x^2}{25}+\mathcal{O}(x^3).$$
Therefore, only including the highest order, the expansion reads:
$$\sinh^{\frac{1}{5}}(x)=\Big(x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\mathcal{O}(x^5)\Big)^{\frac{1}{5}}=x^{\frac{1}{5}}\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\mathcal{O}(x^4)\Big)^{\frac{1}{5}}=x^{\frac{1}{5}}\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{30}+\mathcal{O}(x^4)\Big).$$
The next highest order term would have the form
\begin{align}
\sinh^{\frac{1}{5}}(x)&=\Big(x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\mathcal{O}(x^7)\Big)^{\frac{1}{5}}\\&=x^{\frac{1}{5}}\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\Big)^{\frac{1}{5}}\\&=x^{\frac{1}{5}}\Big(1+\frac{1}{5}\Big(\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}\Big)-\frac{2}{25}\Big(\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}\Big)^2+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\Big)\\&=x^{\frac{1}{5}}\Big(1+\frac{x^2}{30}-\frac{x^4}{1800} +\mathcal{O}(x^6)\Big)
\end{align}
where in the last line because of the precision up to order $x^6$ the higher order terms from the expansion of $\big(\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}\big)^2$ were discarded. This procedure then can be iterated futher and further for higher orders in the expansion.

**Bonus:** For the more generalized version of your problem, the expansion up to the second highest order has the from
$$\sinh^\alpha(x)=x^\alpha\bigg(1+\frac{\alpha}{6}x^2+\frac{\alpha(5\alpha-2)}{360}x^4+\mathcal{O}(x^6)\bigg).$$

Answer (score 3):

If you want a series expansion with integer power, let $x=t^5$
$$y=\sqrt[5]{\sinh \left(t^5\right)}\implies \log(y)=\frac 15 \log \left(\sinh \left(t^5\right)\right)$$ Now, compose series (one piece at the time)
$$\sinh \left(t^5\right)=t^5+\frac{t^{15}}{6}+\frac{t^{25}}{120}+\frac{t^{35}}{5040}+\frac{t^{45}}{362880}+O\left(t^{55}\right)$$
$$\log \left(\sinh \left(t^5\right)\right)=5 \log
   (t)+\frac{t^{10}}{6}-\frac{t^{20}}{180}+\frac{t^{30}}{2835}-\frac{t^{40}}{37800}+
   O\left(t^{50}\right)$$
$$\log(y)=\log
   (t)+\frac{t^{10}}{30}-\frac{t^{20}}{900}+\frac{t^{30}}{14175}-\frac{t^{40}}{18900
   0}+O\left(t^{50}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=t+\frac{t^{11}}{30}-\frac{t^{21}}{1800}+\frac{t^{31}}{25200}-\frac{131
   t^{41}}{45360000}+O\left(t^{51}\right)$$

Comment: Interesting way to circumvent the singularity !

Comment: So, the first line is the expansion considering the exponential representation of sinh(x). What steps are involved in going from the first line (sinh) to the second line (log(sinh))? You can't just take log of every term in the first expansion, right?

Comment: Judging by the alternating signs on the expansion of log(sinh(t^5)), I would think the terms are obtained by the series expansion of log, which contains a (-1)^k. Still, I don’t see how you get those values for the log expansion or how you use the expansion of sinh to obtain them in the first place. Could you offer some brief clarification for that step?

Comment: @paulbernays. It is just the binomial expansion. This is why I gave all the steps in detail.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici binomial expansion... of what two terms?

Comment: @paulbernays. Good point ! There are two ways to do it. Suppose that you want the series of $e^{f(x)}$. You can use the series of $e^t$ and replace $t$ by $f(x)$ and continue expansion. You can also expand $f(x)$ and take the expoential (here is the binomial expansion).

Comment: I would have gone for $x^{1/5}(\sinh x/x) ^{1/5}$ and then used binomial, but your approch avoids fractional exponents. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. There are so many ways ! I must confess that I am often surprised to notice how many people refuse fractional exponents. Thanks and cheers :-)